# HTML/CSS buttons acting weird on mobile (Chrome/Android)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple HTML, CSS website that is also making use of JavaScript for animated navigation for a mobile only site.

[Current Naviation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzE4Z.png)

The HTML for the button:

```html
<div class="navigations">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="leftinner" id="left">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
            <span id="lefttext">CONTACT</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="rightinner" id="right">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            <span id="righttext">WEBSITE</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the contact button it triggers a JS function that runs the following:

```
document.getElementById('main').classList.add('slideright');
document.getElementById('left').style.display = 'none';
```

The issue I am having is when the user clicks the CONTACT button it triggers the WEBSITE button as well, almost as if the WEBSITE button has a hidden overlap over the CONTACT button. I have attempted using Flex Box, Float left, Float left and right, Display inline block, Display table with table-cell, column etc. The issue only persists on Chrome for Android, but works fine on iPhone and other browsers.

What would be the best way to fix this issue?

Apologies I can't share more than just the screenshot due to NDA reasons.

### Edit

Here is the CSS for the navigation buttons, this uses the float left and right attempt.

```css
.navigations .left {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 500;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.navigations .left .leftinner {
    background-color: #ffcb05;
    border-top: 6px solid #000;
    border-right: 3px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navigations .right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 500;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

.navigations .right .rightinner {
    background-color: #ffcb05;
    border-top: 6px solid #000;
    border-left: 3px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: can you at least share the css used for this block of elements?

Comment: Some troubleshooting leads: in the event handler console.log the event.target to confirm what's being clicked. Just a random what-if: if you attached the event listener to something by a class name and then changed the class name the event listener wouldn't move. If you haven't already: you can plug your Android phone into the computer to use Chrome's dev tools for debugging.

Comment: @ZiadDarwich I have added the CSS used for the left and right buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve the issue with this.

Seems the float right on the text inside the right hand side button was the culprit. Changing how the right button moved its text to the right by making use of `text-align: right;`instead of `float: right;` solved the issue.

It seems that the floating right of text made the text's width 100% and overlap the button on the left.